# Array de componentes React com Typescript(.tsx)

Tags: json, react, typescript, next.js

Tenho um pequeno projeto utilizando Next.js, React e TypeScript.

A ideia é que um conjunto de valores dentro de um array num arquivo .json seja transformado nos componentes React e dispostos na pagina depois.

componente.tsx:

```
import styles from '../styles/BlocoTarefa.module.css'

interface Tarefa {
    materia: string,
    local: string,
    descricao: string,
    data: string,
}

export default function BlocoTarefa(props: Tarefa) {
    return(
        <div className={styles.tarefaContainer}>
            <div className={styles.left}>
                <div>Matéria: {props.materia}</div>
                <div>Atividade: {props.descricao}</div>
                <div><span>Local de envio: {props.local}</span><span className={styles.data}>Data de Entrega: {props.data}</span></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="cbx" className={styles.cbx} />
                <label htmlFor="cbx" className={styles.check}>
                     check
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

data.json

```
[
    {
        "materia": "LPI",
        "local": "AVA",
        "descricao": "Entrada e saída de dados",
        "data": "04/03"
    },
    {
        "materia": "MAT",
        "local": "EMAIL",
        "descricao": "Resolver e enviar",
        "data": "04/03"
    }
]
```

atualmente a estrutura de pasta está assim: (não sou bom em digitar isso, perdão)

```
Projeto
|
|-- Public
|      |
|      |-- data.json
|
|
src -- components -- componente.tsx
|
|
pages -- index.tsx
```

Estou tendo dificuldades principalmente em carregar o json.

Comment: Qual sua duvida?

Comment: de como fazer isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Data from 'data.json'

interface Tarefa {
  materia: string,
  local: string,
  descricao: string,
  data: string
}

interface TarefaProps {
  tarefa: Tarefa[]
}

const TarefaExample: React.FC<TarefaProps> = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Tarefa[]>()

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(Data)
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {data?.map((n) => {
        return (
          //Renderize sua tela
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```

Lembre-se dos estudos com typescript que você tem que fazer as declarações e apontar no seu componente/classe qual interface ele deve seguir.

- Use o state para definir o estado inicial da aplicação.
- Use o useEffect para fazer alterar seus dados antes da aplicação iniciar.

Se necessario, adicione um loading na sua aplicação.